# Open an ionic modal when clicking a button with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

I'm a newby in AngularJS and maybe I'm missing something stupid but I cannot get my ionic modal work out. I need that a modal open up when I click the share button, but I get in console Error: $scope.modal is undefined. I'm not sure why. This is my code right now. Any help will be apreciated.

modal.html

```
<ion-modal-view>
  <ion-header-bar>
    <h1 class="title">My Modal title</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    Hello!
  </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

members.html (This is where I have my share button)

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="secondary">
  <button class="button button-clear"  ng-click="openModal()">
    <span class="share-button">Share</span>
  </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

controller.js

```
.controller('MembersCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.modal.remove();
  });
})
```

Comment: Since I can't see all of your code, I would like to know if the issue is isolated to the modal itself, and not related to your app setup. Can you tell me, if you change your `openModal()` function to remove `$scope.modal.show()`, and replace it with `alert("test");`, do you get any errors?

Comment: If I replace it with alert("test") it works fine and I don't get an error. So I think the issue is isolated to the modal itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `modal.html` is stored in a `templates` folder, can you try adding `templates/` or whatever the path is:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
```

Comment: Yes, it has worked¡ The path was the problem. Thanks for your help.